# using index in a path in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use the index in a for loop and store it in a variable.
I wrote a batch file with this code:

```
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,3) DO (
    ECHO %%x
    SET tmp=prefix_%%x.suffix
    ECHO tmp is %tmp%
)
```

when running it, I get:

```
1
tmp is prefix_3.suffix
2
tmp is prefix_3.suffix
3
tmp is prefix_3.suffix
```

i would expect it to be:

```
1
tmp is prefix_1.suffix
2
tmp is prefix_2.suffix
3
tmp is prefix_3.suffix
```

what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 4):

```
Setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,3) DO (
    ECHO %%x
    SET tmp=prefix_%%x.suffix
    ECHO tmp is !tmp!
)
```

All the block in the for command is evaluated when it is readed. %%x changes are seen as it is a special variable known to change during loops, but %tmp% is only translated once, at the start and is not reevaluated. Enabling delayed expansion and changing sintax to `!tmp!` instructs cmd to reevaluate the variable each time it is accessed.

Comment: wow, this was my first question on stack overflow, and just a perfect answer. thank you :-)

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson moment! `TMP` should be set to the same as `TEMP` and should point to a directory to store temporary files. Some older software may make this assumption and if you change it, the software may act unpredictably (one of a number of predefined variables that it's best not to change - for an incomplete list,type `SET` at the prompt...) Also, the response `prefix_3` is a hangover from a prior run when the variable was established. Hence the common use of a `setlocal` as the first command of a batch - this ensures that changes made by a batch are backed out when the batch ends.